# How to solve undefined getactivity in android application?

Tags: android, list, static

I have this piece of code I want to show this dummy data in a static list but I get error in extends fragment and also in get activity, how can I solve them? Do I need to change any part of it?

```
 public class AgendaFragment extends Fragment{

    private ArrayAdapter<String> magendaAdapter;

public AgendaFragment() {
}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        String[] data = {
                "Monday  going to restaurant at 14",
                "Monday  going to restaurant at 1",
                "Monday  going to restaurant at 1",
        };
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));


        magendaAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                        R.layout.list_item_agenda, // The name of the layout ID.
                        R.id.list_item_agenda_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                        weekForecast);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_agenda);
        listView.setAdapter(magendaAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                String forecast = magendaAdapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), forecast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are the errors? Are they compiler or runtime errors? Please update the post with compiler output and/or logcat dump if it's runtime error.

Comment: Error:(25, 41) error: cannot find symbol class Fragment
Error:(54, 29) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()
Error:(62, 70) error: cannot find symbol variable listview_agenda
Error:(69, 36) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()
Error:(33, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

at the beginning of your code file.

(or `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` if you are using Android support library)

Comment: @Anita It's a different question, here in comments it's total mess anyway